# add, edit, delete and share from custom list view and what data storage to use in android

Tags: android, database, android-fragments, android-custom-view, android-database

I've been searching for an answer for this but still didn't found what I need.

I'm developing an android app that works with 2 fragments and each one have custom list view.
In the first fragment, I want to add a new item in list view and have the options to delete, edit or share.
On sharing item will be to shared to the listview of the 2nd fragment.

The 2nd fragment is where all users can see what other users have shared and also can add it to there list in the first fragment.

There will be a offline/local database(first fragment) and online database( 2nd fragment )

---

My question is what kind of storage I can use for that?
Also, how it will deal with the add, edit, share and delete?

I wish i can have some help, thank you
ps: I designed everything i need.. but I just stopped in the storage part.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options to store data. First you can use the SQL lite database to store values or you can use NoSQL database like JSON where each and every value will be stored in the form of key value pair and light weighted.

When you want to remove some value form the list then firstly remove the value from the actual database and then from current ArrayAdapter of the list and at last attach the adapter to the view.